Applying Incremental Refresh with Detect Data Changes for Dimension Tables in Power BI Premium
I’m working with a Power BI Premium dataset where I’ve successfully configured incremental refresh with the Detect Data Changes feature for fact tables. However, I’m facing a challenge with dimension tables.
I don’t want dimension tables to refresh every time I trigger a dataset refresh. Instead, I want to configure Detect Data Changes for dimension tables so they only refresh when the source data changes.
Is there a way to apply incremental refresh with Detect Data Changes specifically for dimension tables without refreshing them unnecessarily during a dataset refresh?
I tried to create a dummy Date on the dimension where I put the first day of the current year for all the rows, but this is not working because process will create duplicates on the partitions for the next year.
